# php session variable doesn't update on post

Tags: php, arrays, session

I've had this problem for a couple days now and I've been trying different things to attempt to fix it and I'm not getting anywhere.  Basically I'm pulling in data from a database, displaying the data using a loop, adding a "delete" button, and storing the data in a session array.

When the user presses the delete button the page refreshes but my session variable isn't being updated.  Can anyone tell me why?  I'm using the if isset 'POST' to update my session variable.  FYI there's a lot of extra echoes in my code just so I can see what's going on.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I also threw in a JavaScript popup to see if the if statement was working.  The popup is not coming up either.

```
<?php
function multilineQ($con, $sql)
{
    $x = 0; // incremented for the ex number

    if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql))
        {
          do
            {
            // Store first result set
                if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con))
                {
                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        $button = "ex" . $x . "Button";
                        echo "<ex id=\"ex$x\">";
                        echo    $row['ExType'] . ' ----- ' . $row['ExName'] . " " .
                                "<input type=\"submit\" 
                                        name=\"$button\"
                                        value=\"Delete\"> " .
                                " - <b>Button Name: </b>" . $button;
                        echo    "<br />";
                        echo "</ex>"; 

                        // Add to Array
                        // ----------------------
                        $_SESSION['exArray'][$x][0] = 1;
                        $_SESSION['exArray'][$x][1] = $row['ExType'];
                        $_SESSION['exArray'][$x][2] = $row['ExName'];
                        // ----------------------

                        // If delete button pressed...
                        // ----------------------
                        echo "$button If statement created <br /><br />";
                        if (isset($_POST['$button'])) 
                        { 
                            $_SESSION['exArray'][$x][0] = 0;
                            $foo = "Alert: " .  $_SESSION['exArray'][$x][3] . " : Deleted.";
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$foo')</script>";
                        }
                        // ----------------------

                        $x++; // Increment number
                    }
                    mysqli_free_result($con);
                }
            } while (mysqli_next_result($con));
        } else
        {
            echo 'Could not run SQL...';
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: add session_start() on the top of your file ..

Comment: `$button` is in single quotes. That indentation is also painful to read :<

Comment: Thanks, I see what your saying.  I removed the quotes but that didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need add the `session_start()` on the first statement.

```
    <?php
here> session_start();
      function multilineQ($con, $sql)
      {
```

Comment: This file is being included in another file that has a session_start at the top.  Sorry I've only included part of my code here.

Comment: you need to add session_start(); here to set the session variable.

Comment: I tried adding this but it didn't change anything.  My session variable seems to be working.  The lines of the query are being added to the variable with no problem it's just when I use the delete button the if doesn't seem to be working. Thank you for your suggestion.